# Security in Object Oriented Java Programming and Static Factory Constructors

Tags: java

I have a Person class and a Staff and Student class based off of Person.

Then we have a ManagePeople class that is a menu for adding a person/staff/student and their information.

The thing is, we have to make a static factory method:

```
public static Person getInstance(String name, String age)
```

method because we are making our program secure.

My problem is when I try to add a Student object to an Array in ManagePeople

```
ArrayList<Person> people
```

It says that it cannot. Can anyone shed some light on this problem?

Comment: We aren't allowed to use inheritance

Comment: You can't add one class to an `ArrayList` of a different class. If you can't use inheritance, then this just won't work.

Comment: I tried casting to a person, didn

Comment: Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: "_I have a Person class and a Staff and Student class based off of Person._" but you can't use inheritance ... your requirement don't make sense... "_based of_" suggest _inherit_  !

Answer (score 0):

If you're not allowed to use inheritance then I suggest changing `Person` from a `class` to an `interface`.  Then all the required methods can be specified and all the different classes can be added to the list.

Comment: That would not makes sense (even if it would work) because you can't add the attributes of a person into the interface (firstname, lastname, ...) and the corresponding constructors.

Comment: That is true. But you can provide getters and setters in the interface to overcome that problem. I'm not saying its an elegant solution, but its a way to avoid using inheritance.